# Redux-Persist not persisting one slice of the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage, redux-persist

I'm using react-redux with redux-persist in a React application with multiple slices of state. It is a simple app with slices such as `ui`, `todolist`, `notes`, and `todolist-projects`. All of the slices of state are persisting except for the `todolist` slice.

Below is my `store/index.js` where I initialize the store and persistor:

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import { rootReducer } from "./rootReducer";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

I read something inside of a GitHub issue about the `key` prop sometimes needing to be set to `"primary"` instead of `"root"`. In the Chrome DevTools, in the localStorage debugging area, I noticed that the `todolist` slice does seem to be persisting in the `persist:primary` section. (see the screenshot below.)
[image: Screenshot from Chrome DevTools]

I tried changing `key` from `"root"` to `"primary"` but this does not seem to be working. It didn't seem to make a difference.

You can see this project live on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/christian-js/home-suite/main?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A1%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhs0pt4y000a2v6kygfwpmk5%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhs0pt4y000c2v6kp4cl4lmu%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B36.15390585587333%252C63.84609414412667%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clhs0pt4y000a2v6kygfwpmk5%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhs0pt4y000a2v6kygfwpmk5%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clhs0q47q006n2v6ktm4518r6%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhs0pt4y00092v6k4sb94rpv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpackage.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhs0q47q006n2v6ktm4518r6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clhs0pt4y000c2v6kp4cl4lmu%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhs0pt4y000c2v6kp4cl4lmu%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clhs0qfrg00f62v6kev4nan0e%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhs0qcx200a52v6kkyff4kzd%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhs0qfrg00f62v6kev4nan0e%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Ftodolist%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: What, or where, is this todo list reducer? You mention state slices, are you using redux-toolkit by any chance? Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] that includes all relevant code being used?

Comment: @DrewReese I am not using RTK, I am using react-redux. I should note that this app worked perfectly until recently and I am not sure what changed and caused the issue.

Comment: Well, this is just one dev's opinion, but it's 2023 and we don't really bother writing bulky legacy redux code anymore; it's highly suggested to start using RTK as it significantly reduces the amount of boilerplate code you need to write. I don't see any overt issues here with the persist logic that would preclude specifically the `state.todoList` state from being persisted, e.g. it's not black listed in the persist configuration. Think you could stand up a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese Okay I added a CodeSandbox link where you can try it for yourself.

Comment: There unfortunately appears to be an issue trying to load the codesandbox you linked in your post.

Comment: @DrewReese My apologies, I have corrected the link and it should work now

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll take a look when I have availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

The `state.todolist` is being persisted to localStorage, as evidenced by your screenshot. There were a few issues I found in the code in your sandbox though.

1. `NavBar` is using raw anchor (`<a>`) tags instead of the `react-router-dom` `Link` component to effect navigation actions. These will reload the page and reset any local React component state.
2. The `Todolist` component was using an incorrect object reference comparison to filter the selected `state.todolist` state against the current `state.ui.currTodoProject` value. These are both objects and after the state has been JSON serialized into localStorage and then JSON deserialized back into the Redux store, these will no longer have shallow reference equality... they are completely new and different objects.

## Suggested Solution

Update `NavBar` to use the `Link` component.

```
import "./NavBar.styles.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { persistor } from "../../../store/index.js";

const NavBar = () => {
  const purgeCache = () => {
    persistor
      .purge()
      .then(() => console.log("Cache Pruged!"))
      .catch(() => console.log("Could Not Purge Cache..."));
  };
  
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/todolist">Todo List</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/notes">Notes</Link>
        </li>
        <li style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={purgeCache}>
          <Link to="/">Purge Store</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Update `Todolist` compare the project objects *by their `_id` properties. There's also no need to duplicate the todolist into any local state, simply compute the current `currTodos` value from the selected `todolist` state.

```
const currTodos = todolist.filter(
  (t) => t.project._id === ui.currTodoProject._id
);
```

If computed this derived state is expensive use the `useMemo` hook to memoize the computed value. In fact, just about any time you see yourself writing a `useState`/`useEffect` hook combo, this is what `useMemo` is for.

```
const currTodos = useMemo(() => todolist.filter(
  (t) => t.project._id === ui.currTodoProject._id
), [todolist, ui.currTodoProject._id]);
```

```
...

const Todolist = () => {
  const todolist = useSelector((state) => state.todolist);
  const projects = useSelector((state) => state.todolistProjects);
  const ui = useSelector((state) => state.ui);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [deletedTodo, setDeletedTodo] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(changeTodoProject(projects[0]));
  }, []);

  const currTodos = todolist.filter(
    (t) => t.project._id === ui.currTodoProject._id
  );
  
  ...

  return (
    <div id="todolist" onClick={handleContainerClick}>
      ...
      {currTodos.map((todo) => {
        return (
          <Todo
            todo={todo}
            key={todo._id}
            showDeleteDialog={showDeleteDialog}
            setDeletedTodo={setDeletedTodo}
          />
        );
      })}
      ...
    </div>
  );
};

export default Todolist;
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you for the detailed answer, you also helped me learn a little more about React state and how to manage it